# Why aren't S_IRWXG and S_IRWXO defined in sys/types.h on Windows?

Tags: c++, unix, windows-xp, porting, systypes.h

I'm porting some software to Window from Unix and am using the g++ v4.7 on Windows XP SP3.  I have a header file declaration that looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

bool MakeDir(const string &dirName,
             mode_t mode =S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

```
FileName.h:35:40: error: 'S_IRWXG' was not declared in this scope
FileName.h:35:50: error: 'S_IRWXO' was not declared in this scope
```

Why would `sys/types.h` define `S_IRWXU` but not `S_IRWXG` nor `S_IRWXO`?

I found some code that defines them on Windows like this:

```
#define S_IRWXG (S_IRWXU >> 3)
#define S_IRWXO (S_IRWXG >> 3)
```

This seems like a kludge and apt to break, is there a better way to get definitions for  these?  I do not want to use Cygwin.

Comment: per this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(v=vs.80).aspx windows still has a sys/stat.h, so #include <sys/stat.h> will add those missing macros.

Comment: As shown above, I am already including `<sys/stat.h>`.  I also tried adding `<sys/types.h>` above it, but that does not help.  Perhaps I am missing some -D preprocessor flag to get them defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S_IRWXG and S_IRWXO are actual for Linux, on Windows you don't need them, 
values you can just get from Linux

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP does not have the concept group and other permissions in its file system, hence, these macros are not defined.